# Meu site não atualiza o CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, ssl

Pessoal eu fiz algumas modificações no meu site apenas no CSS. Entretanto, ele não atualiza as modificações só que eu percebi que tirando o 'https' e colocando apenas o 'http' ele modifica, é como se eu estivesse configurando o site apenas no domínio com http. Meu site é desenvolvido com WordPress. Se alguem puder me dar uma luz eu agradeço.

Comment: Provavelmente o seu arquivo de estilo está guardado em cache.

Comment: Tente também se ainda não tentou, atualizar sua página com o (CTRL + F5), dessa forma ele atualiza e limpa o cache, vê se funciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite.
Tenho esse problema constantemente quando uso o Chrome.
A solução é bem simples:
► Configurações ► Avançado ► Limpar dados de navegação ► (Deixe marcado apenas) 
Imagens e arquivos armazenados em cache ► Click em limpar dados.

Certamente sua pagina voltará a atualizar.

Caso esteja usando outro navegador procure limpar o cache.

Espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

tenho uma solução extremamente simples.

No Chrome:

Abra o DevTools pressionando a tecla F12

Selecione a Aba Network marque a caixa **Disable cache**

Pressione F12 para sair do DevTools ou click no botão fechar à direita das abas

Recarregue a página!

Tenha uma boa noite!